# Ruby on Rails nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bigdecimal

Why do I get `nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal` when I try to perform a calculation: here's the code:

**model/drink.rb**

```
class Drink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu 
  before_save :total_amount 

def total_amount
    self.total_amount = self.price * self.quantity
end
```

**model/menu.rb**

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :drinks, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :drinks, :allow_destroy => true
    #Validations

end
```

**Drink is the (nested)child model and Menu the parent model* When I attempt to create a new drink the browser display following error message  `nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal  app/models/drink.rb:7:in 'total-amount'
app/controllers/menus_controller.rb:47:in 'create'
app/controllers/menus_controller.rb:46:in 'create'`

app/db/migration

```
class CreateDrinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :drinks do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.decimal :quantity,:precision => 8, :scale => 2
      t.decimal :price, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
      t.decimal :vat, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
      t.references :menu

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :drinks, :menu_id
  end
end
```

**controllers/drinks_controller.rb**

```
   class DrinksController < ApplicationController
      # GET /drinks
      # GET /drinks.json
      def index
        @drinks = Drink.all

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render :json => @drinks }
        end
      end

      # GET /drinks/1
      # GET /drinks/1.json
      def show
        @drink = Drink.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # show.html.erb
          format.json { render :json => @drink }
        end
      end

      # GET /drinks/new
      # GET /drinks/new.json
      def new
        @drink = Drink.new

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render :json => @drink }
        end
      end

      # GET /drinks/1/edit
      def edit
        @drink = Drink.find(params[:id])
      end

      # POST /drinks
      # POST /drinks.json
      def create
        @article = Drink.new(params[:drink])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @drink.save
            format.html { redirect_to @drink, :notice => 'Drink was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :json => @drink, :status => :created, :location => @article }
          else
            format.html { render :action => "new" }
            format.json { render :json => @drink.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PUT /drinks/1
      # PUT /drinks/1.json
      def update
        @drink = Drink.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @drink.update_attributes(params[:drink])
            format.html { redirect_to @drink, :notice => 'Drink was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :ok }
          else
            format.html { render :action => "edit" }
            format.json { render :json => @drink.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /drinks/1
      # DELETE /drinks/1.json
      def destroy
        @drink = Drink.find(params[:id])
        @drink.destroy

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to drinks_url }
          format.json { head :ok }
        end
      end 
    end
```

Please can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code?

Comment: What values do you get for `price` and `quantity` in `total_amount`? Do a `Logger.debug "#{self.price} #{self.quantity}"` as the first line in `total_amount`.

Comment: here is what I get with 'Logger.debug...' as the first line in total_amount method `undefined method 'debug' for Logger:Class`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want nil to be evaluated as 0.0 then you can do something like this:

```
def total_amount
    self.total_amount = self.price.to_s.to_d * self.quantity.to_s.to_d
end
```

Or explicitly check for nil

```
def total_amount
  if self.price && self.quantity
    self.total_amount = self.price * self.quantity
  else
    self.total_amount = "0.0".to_d
  end
end
```

The problem is really that your record fields aren't set like you expect them to be.  Do you need to use validations to make sure that the `price` and `quantity` fields are set?

```
class Drink
  validates :price, :presence => true      # Don't forget add DB validations, too :)
  validates :quantity, :presence => true
end
```

That way you ensure that you don't get a nil value when calling #total_amount.

Comment: Your solution help me to invoke the total_amount method in views too. You can see the issue on the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774638/ruby-on-rails-calculation

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting the `quantity` value anywhere so it is `nil` and `nil` cannot be coerced into a number for the multiplication.

Presumably your `price` is a `decimal(n,2)` (for some `n`) in the database so `self.price` is represented in Ruby as a BigDecimal object; that's why you're getting complaints about not being able to coerce to BigDecimal.

You can get a similar error out of `irb` like this:

```
>> 11 * nil
TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
    from (irb):7:in `*'
```

Your `self.price` is set though. If it wasn't then you'd get one of these:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass
```

You might want to add

```
validates_presence_of :quantity, :price
```

(or possible stricter validations) to your model if you're requiring that they be set.

Comment: Sorry man but I don't get the point?Is it a migration problem?I'm a newbie so please be specific because certain things can sounds very abstract to me.

Comment: @blawzoo: Why do expect `self.quantity` to be set to anything at all? Maybe you should include the controller code that builds your objects. Somewhere you're building a Drink but not telling it what the `quantity` is so the quantity is `nil.`

Comment: I've put drink controller and migration.Why can't I reach quantity (which is a defined attribute of drink) in the total_amount method

Comment: @blawzoo: Apparently you don't have a quantity in `params[:drink]`. What does the editing view look like?

Comment: I finally get the point by combining your response with the Wizard of Ogz one