# Rails sum related records in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is what I am doing on my rails app and its working but I am looking for a cleaner solution:

```
class Workorder < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, :through => :tasks
  def total_hours
    events.map{|e| e.hours}.reduce(:+)
  end
```

It gives me the total hours all of the task events:

```
workorder.total_hours
```

But, I also have workorders that have children:

```
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Workorder", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
```

I would like to know the total hours for all of the children and their tasks.

These don't work:

```
  def total_children_hours
    self.children.events.map{|e| e.hours}.reduce(:+)
  end

  I get - undefined method `events'

  def total_children_hours
    self.children.map{|e| e.total_hours}.reduce(:+)
  end

  I get - nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you have many children(s). And each one of them has many events.

```
def total_children_hours
  hours = 0
  self.children(s).each do |children|
    hours += children.events.map{|e| e.hours}.to_i.reduce(:+)
  end
  hours
end
```

Check this similar thread:

[Ruby on Rails nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779368/ruby-on-rails-nil-cant-be-coerced-into-bigdecimal)

ActiveRecord::Calculations

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html

Comment: Thanks for the help.  With your solution, I'm getting "nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal"

Comment: I changed self.children(s).each to self.children.each

Comment: You are getting a nil result that is trying to be added. Convert it to integer with: to_i.

Comment: I modified a little and it worked `      hours += child.events.map{|e| e.hours}.reduce(:+) if child.events.count > 0`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have looked at [ActiveRecord Calculations.html](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) but you can do

```
def total_hours
  events.sum(:hours)
end

def total_children_hours
   events.children.sum(:hours)
end
```

I think that this is the easiest way to make a sum of a column

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution:

```
class Workorder < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :events, :through => :tasks
   def total_hours
     events.map {|e| e.hours }.reduce(:+) || 0
   end
end

def total_children_hours
   children.map {|e| e.total_hours }.reduce(:+)
end
```